# Pedals with largest outside platform area

Tags: pedals-flat

I am 86 years of age with RA and badly splayed out feet. I already have pedal extenders on my custom 350 watt ebike trike (on a Biria frame) and have wrapped rug/carpet laying  tape around the pedals with the rough gritty surface up - to no avail.

I have tried Amazon and eBay and can't identify a wide platform bike pedal that might solve my problem. Does any body out there have a solution or recommendation. Be an angel. Mike Crombie

Comment: Michael, I'm sorry I'm so dense but is the problem that your feet slide off the pedals?

Comment: Can you measure the current spacing between your pedals/feet as they are, and what you estimate would be preferable?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that  my splayed out (30 degrees) feet do slide off the pedals.

Comment: While I like Criggie's suggestion, im wondering if the person who did the customization of the bike could help do some more fit (and/or a sports doctor); I'm a bit wary of hackery with such advanced age (but applause for continuing to ride) and the biomechanics.

Answer (score 4):

Something like the [Crank Bros Stamp](https://www.crankbrothers.com/products/stamp-1-large) pedals might work. The large version are recommended for people with size 10-15 feet, and they also have metal pins that stick out allowing your shoe to grip onto the pedal better.

It might make sense to go to a local bike shop to see what help they can give you. Seeing the pedals in person might let you know if they can work. Or they might be able connect you with someone in your area that modifies bicycles for people with mobility issues.

Answer (score 2):

Are you handy with tools?  Could be worth fitting an aluminium plate to your existing pedals that gives more surface area.  Or even a wooden plate if you prefer.  This would provide more width and/or length to press on.

Another option is to try heel-pedalling, where you press with the heel instead of the ball of the foot.  Downside your foot is weirdly further forward, which can cause toe strike on the front wheel.